# Missing required property 'OutputPath' for project type 'PackageReference'

Tags: msbuild, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run the following command thru Jenkins Pipeline

```
bat 'nuget restore mySolution.sln -MSBuildPath "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin"'
```

but i'm getting error saying

> Invalid restore input. Missing required property 'OutputPath' for
>   project type 'PackageReference'. Input files: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\My Project Build
>   Pipeline\myProject\myProject.csproj.

I tried

```
bat label: '', script: '"C:\\Package tools\\nuget.exe" restore "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\My Project Build Pipeline\\myProject\\myProject.csproj" -MSBuildPath "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin"'  // Restore packages.
```

I'm expecting all the NuGet packages to get installed as we 'Restore NuGet Packages' in Visual Studio.

Comment: And do you have an `outputPath` in your `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\My Project Build Pipeline\myProject\myProject.csproj`?

Comment: Yes I have it under property groups, `<OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>`

Comment: This OutputPath property sits under `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">`

Comment: This is not found under `PackageReference`. And thats what the error is. I tried reading thru msdn.. but could not find what i wanted.

Comment: I tried updating nuget as well based on https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/3000, but no help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently you are using VS 2015 tools (MSBuild 14) and/or an older nuget.exe (< 4.0.0) to work on projects using the `PackageReference` way of referencing NuGet Packages. Use newer tools (Nuget 4+, VS / Build Tools 2017+) to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks. I am using VS 2019 and NuGet 4+. but it was picking MSBuild version 14. I had to point it to the latest MSBuild which sits in the Microsoft Visual Studio in program files.

Comment: I recommend using [vswhere](https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere) to find msbuild locations and nuget should be able to pick up the correct path as well by default.. if you are using VS 2019, I suggest using NuGet 5+. If you are using only PackageReference based projects, you can directly use msbuild and pass `/restore` to it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by running the powershell command:

```
Install-Module VSSetup -Scope CurrentUser
```