# Azure Pipeline deploy to Web App Service failing with Missing required property 'OutputPath'

Tags: c#, .net, azure, bitbucket, azure-pipelines

I am running into an issue with deploying to Azure Web App resource I've got set up. I can't find much about this error online so posting here...

I have a .NET solution with a main project and several class library projects which i make references to in my main project.

For some reason, the deployment is failing because it doesn't pick up those dll projects in the solution. My code is on a bitbucket repo and I've set it to deploy to my web app resource whenever I make a commit to a certain branch.

But it is failing with this error:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
Invalid restore input. Missing required property 'OutputPath' for project type 'PackageReference'. Input files: D:\home\site\repository\XXXCode\XXXXX.Entities\XXXXX.Entities.csproj.
Failed exitCode=1, command=nuget restore "D:\home\site\repository\XXXCode\XXXCode.sln"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Invalid restore input. Missing required property 'OutputPath' for project type 'PackageReference'. Input files: D:\home\site\repository\XXXCode\XXXXX.Entities\XXXXX.Entities.csproj.\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\82.10503.3890\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

Am i missing a step here? 
I'm new to this so I probably forgot a step somewhere.
Any help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64'.

According to this error message, apparently the version you are using is **MSBuild 14.0(VS 2015 tools)**.

And also, from this message:

> Missing required property 'OutputPath' for project type
>   'PackageReference'.

As far as I understood, the `PackageReference` just works with **MSBuild version 15** and higher, instead of 14.0. Since it came with VS 2017, and at the same time MSBuild 15.0.

So, for solve this error, I recommend you try with the newer version: **MSbuild 15.0.**

You can also refer to this ticket: [Missing required property 'OutputPath' for project type 'PackageReference'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021192/missing-required-property-outputpath-for-project-type-packagereference)

**Edit:**

First, please ensure that your script can be executed successfully in VS2017 locally.

And then, if you build with **Visual Studio build task**, change the `Visual Studio Version` as:

[image]

Or, if its **MSBuild task** you are using, just need to change the `MSBuild Version`:

[image]

On the other hand, if you are using `Specify Location` instead of `Version` in MSbuild task, specify the location path of **MSBuild.exe** which under MSBuild 15.0. For me, I am using VS2019, so the location of MSbuild 16.0 is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

[image]

**Update**:

Since you are using VS2017, you can specified the location of MSbuild 15.0 with your **MSbuild 15.0 file path** as:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64
```

Comment: Thank you. I currently have VS2017. The project may have started with VS2015 but then moved to 2017. Do you know how I have this project point to MsBuild 15.0?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it and feel free to let me know the latest progress;-)

Comment: @BellaGurl Hi, how are thins going? Can you located to the msbuild 15.0 correctly and execute your build successfully now?